# in this situation is find my iphone on in my idevice?

Tags: icloud, restore

heyi recently bought an already used iphone and decided to upgrade it 
now when i did so there was no message on itunes saying to turn find my iphone off or anything like that it was upgraded it successfully but when i do my emei check online . it keeps telling me that find my iphone is on 
any ideas ?? 
would i be able to upgrade or restore my iphone if find my iphone is on ???
or is it off in my situation means there is no icloud account ???
any thoughts ?

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> iCloud
If it's not enabled in there, it is not enabled on the device.

Comment: right now i upgraded the iphone and it's stuck on sim activation in setup . asi said i bought this iphone via another person and i was wondering should get a nano sim card and activate it ? will i get the icloud activation or will it be just the sim activation ? i read several arcticles concerning the restore and it says that if i find my iphone is on then one cannot restore any thoughts ?

Comment: If the previous owner has not removed it from iCloud you cannot bypass the activation lock at all.